# IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory / in package

Tags: python, python-module

Below is my **init**.py which is located under pkg/settings

```
import yaml
import os

def Keypairs():
    print os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    with open('keypairs.yaml') as f:
        return yaml.load(f)
```

I run the package: `python -m pkg.test.first` which has a relative import:

```
from ..settings    import Keypairs    
print Keypairs()
```

But I get

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'keypairs.yaml'
```

although the structure is:

```
pkg/
  __init__.py
  settings/
    __init__.py
    keypairs.yaml
  test/
    __init__.py
    first.py
```

What am I messing with the directories?

If I run the `__init__.py` (which is in settings) as a script it locates the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edited**

You are opening the file in the wrong directory, importing a module does not change your working directory. Do this instead

```
 import yaml 
 import os

 def Keypairs():
   print os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

   with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirpath(__file__),'keypairs.yaml')) as f:
     return yaml.load(f)
```

Comment: Thanks, found it as well. The correct is `with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'keypairs.yaml')) as f` since now it takes the current file and adds the `key pairs.yaml` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Well it appears that since I run the file as a package, it takes as parent directory the one where the package is.

So you need to pass

```
basepath = os.path.dirname(__file__)
keypairs = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(basepath, "keypairs.yaml"))
with open(keypairs,'r') as f:
    return yaml.load(f)
```

or if you want an absolute:

```
with open("pkg/settings/keypairs.yaml",'r') as f:
```

And the most clean way with the help of @yorodm

```
with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'keypairs.yaml')) as f:
    return yaml.load(f)
```